# Parse "next day" time

Tags: r, time

Is there a function (built-in or packaged) that would allow parsing a time like `"25:15:00"` as "1:15 on the next day"? Unfortunately, `as.POSIXct` doesn't like it with the `%X` specification (equivalent to `%H:%M:%S`),

```
> as.POSIXct('25:15:00', format='%X')
[1] NA
> as.POSIXct('15:15:00', format='%X')
[1] "2013-05-24 15:15:00 CEST"
```

and I can't find a suitable conversion specification in the [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) docs.

Comment: You could implement one easily.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: I know. I even think I know how to. But that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there is:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('kimisc', 'krlmlr')
library(kimisc)
hms.to.seconds('25:15:00')
```

It uses a slightly different approach than dickoa's code: The argument is filtered by `gsub` using a suitable regular expression, and the actual conversion doesn't involve `strptime` at all. See the [code](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc/blob/master/R/hms_to_seconds.R).

Answer (score 2):

Not thoroughly tested but you can try this function

```
parse_time <- function(x, format = "%X") {
    hour <- as.numeric(substr(x, 1, 2))
    delta <- ifelse(hour >= 24, 24 * 3600, 0)
    hour <- hour %% 24
    date <- paste0(hour, substr(x, 3, nchar(x)))
    strptime(date, format = format) + delta
}

parse_time(c('25:15:00', "23:10:00"))
##[1] "2013-05-25 01:15:00 GMT" "2013-05-24 23:10:00 GMT"
```